# Can't detect if my user goes offline from my site

Tags: jquery, asp-classic, logout, detect

I am developing a community site where many user can join and do some activity...Now a problem arise
and I didn't handle it and need your help ... here is the details

I'm using classic ASP ,php, and jQuery
Have a logout script that works fine
Have a timer that will redirect user to the logout page and that works fine too
Have a jquery .unload() event too

But what if an user didn't go through any of these?
If he power off his pc or turn off the data connection on his mobile/tablet ?
Or any other incident that let him go through the checking ?

Additionally I'm also storing IP address of the user, is there any way to check that IP is still
connected from my server through a code that will run automatically or scheduled so I can change
that user status to the database so the other user will get the exact status of that user.

Regards.
Debasis

Comment: The way I've seen it done is to store a last accessed time stamp. If the user doesn't access the site for x minutes, consider him logged off/inactive.

Comment: Yes but how can I run a script that will run from a server autocratically/infinitely for a given interval

Comment: Basically, you'll have to make the client poll the server somehow (javascript probably) or just count the time from the last loaded page (which, if the user idles will show him/her as offline)

Answer (score 2):

You can either: 
- use websockets to create a bidirectional connection between client and server, this allows you to detect when a client disconnects

Or

- use a mechanism of polling where your client app pings the server to send a keep alive message in a given interval, assume that a client is disconnected when it passed more than that interval without a keep alive message was sent.

Comment: Thought it too but didn't know how to run a script that will continuously checking all the ping from user

Comment: check this: http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery